# How to copy entire database to another?

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a solution to copy the entire database by using MYSQL query.

I am developing a system where admin can create b2c and b2b stores from backend, and for both types of websites, I have a single type of database structure and would like to copy that directly whenever a store will created. So I am looking for a direct query to achieve that instead of a PHP script (already done).

Comment: I would like to copy the empty structure for most of the tables but required data for few tables.

Comment: Create stored procedure which copies (but the best way - creates) all tables' structures (in proper order if FKs exists), additional components (triggers, for example), and copies the data for selected tables. And call it when new DB needed. The only SP parameter is the name of new database. Do not forget to edit SP when source structure altered.

Comment: @Akina: Yes, you are correct but what should I write in a stored procedure? Actually, I am already aware of about 2 solutions, one is outfile and infiles methods and second using the procedure but I am preferring short way and that can only achieve by the trigger. Please guide me for the script if you can.

Comment: *one is outfile and infiles methods* I don't understand what you mean... *that can only achieve by the trigger* MySQL do not support DDL triggers.

Comment: Stop. Thinking more deep I understood that while using SP there is a lot of problems. 1) You can create DB using prepared statement, but you cannot make it current. 2) Triggers and FKs are not copied by CREATE TABLE .. LIKE, and they cannot be created using prepared statement.

Comment: You can check out this post for out-file and infiles methods using MySQL query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195493/export-mysql-database-using-php-only